# XP-CLR error message - Numerical Recipes run-time error

Tags: c++

MY colleagues and I are trying to use the program/method XP-CLR to detect positive selection from genomic data. This programs is detailed in the paper Chen H., Patterson N. & Reich D. (2011) Population differentiation as a test for seletive sweeps. Genomic Research 20, 393-402. The program is written in C++ and we are running it through a University-based cluster.

The programs seems to compile without a problem, but always returns the following error message when run:

g++ -c  xpclr.cpp 
g++ /gpfs/work/g/gdh14/XPCLR/src/HUALIB/p2sweep.o /gpfs/work/g/gdh14/XPCLR/src/HUALIB/hualib.o xpclr.o -o XPCLR
cp XPCLR ../bin
Numerical Recipes run-time error...
allocation failure 2 in matrix()
...now exiting to system...

Has anyone else had a similar problem? And if so, can they suggest a solution?

Comment: You're getting that error when you `cp` the executable?

Comment: Allocation of memory failed. Start up the debugger and set it to break on exceptions. When the runtime failure is triggered it should break out and take you to the line where it occurred. From there backtrace the call stack and check the parameters. One may be wrong or you are allocating more memory than is available.